# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in BioPython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

The below code caused this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/t.py", line 19, in <module>
    seqsInfo[record.id] = SeqInfo(len(record), record.seq[0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

```
from Bio import SeqIO

class SeqInfo():

    def __init__(self, length, seqStart):
        self.length = length
        self.seqStart = seqStart

seqsInfo=[]
for record in SeqIO.parse("data/hybrid.AA.fasta", "fasta"):
    seqsInfo[record.id] = SeqInfo(len(record), record.seq[0])
```

This is the input file:

```
>STRG2.t1 gene=STRG2 seq_id=NbV1Ch01 type=cds
PYKTCHKKFRNKMPSFYLASFCIMVLSFSITFASGNSVSNKTCIDDATIVLSFGLYQNSC
LEAEAIIYSWVERAVSQDPRMAASLLRLHFHDCFVNGCDASVLLDDTPNFIGEKTAAPNL
NSLRGFEVIDSIKADLELACPQTVSCADILAIAARDSVVLSGGWRWKVQMGRKDSLTAST
KAVNNNIPGPNSNIATLVSSFQNIGLSLQDMVTLSGAHTIGSARCSTFSSRLNGGGNSDM
NLDFLQSLQQLCSVSDTNITLANLDDMTPSTFDNQYYVNLLSGKGLLVSDQVLASGDDNT
REIVQTYVDDPSAFFDDFRNSMLKMGSLAPPTGTTGEIRVNCRV
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Is `record.id` a string? Can you add a `print(type(record.id), record.id)` in your loop body?

Comment: Are you sure `record.id` is an integer?

Comment: The others are correct, `record.id` is a string like `"STRG2.t1"` which can't be used to index a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to assign a non integer as an index to a list, it is giving such error. Please change list to dict, because record.id is 'STRG2.t1'. Hopefully this solves the problem:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

class SeqInfo():

    def __init__(self, length, seqStart):
        self.length = length
        self.seqStart = seqStart

seqsInfo={}
for record in SeqIO.parse("data/hybrid.fasta", "fasta"):
    seqsInfo[record.id] = SeqInfo(len(record), record.seq[0])
print(seqsInfo)
```

Output:
{'STRG2.t1': <**main**.SeqInfo object at 0x1178b3710>}